# Set max numbers on array

Tags: php

I use an addon on opencart

it gives random numbers for model

it use array

please take a look of the code below

```
    $shuffleproducts=array("1","9","2","5"); 
    shuffle($shuffleproducts);
    $codeno ='';
    foreach ($shuffleproducts as $codenumber)
    $codeno = $codeno . strval($codenumber);
    $data['model'] = 'MCODE-' . $codeno;
```

The problem is I got 10 numbers but I want only 4

can someone give me the code to do it

Thanks for everyone

Comment: Take a look at `array_slice()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you can use `array_rand` with second parameter:

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($shuffleproducts, 4);
```

This function will return 4 random keys from your array:

```
foreach ($rand_keys as $k) {   
    echo $shuffleproducts[$k];
}
```